# How to use Armadillo Columns/Rows to perform optimised calculations on accesses within the same column

Tags: arrays, performance, indexing, armadillo

What is the best way to manipulate indexing in Armadillo? I was under the impression that it heavily used template expressions to avoid temporaries, but I'm not seeing these speedups.

Is direct array indexing still the best way to approach calculations that rely on consecutive elements within the same array?

Keep in mind, that I hope to parallelise these calculations in the future with TBB::parallel_for (In this case, from a maintainability perspective, it may be simpler to use direct accessing?) These calculations happen in a tight loop, and I hope to make them as optimal as possible.

```
   ElapsedTimer timer;
   int n = 768000;
   int numberOfLoops = 5000;
   arma::Col<double> directAccess1(n);
   arma::Col<double> directAccess2(n);
   arma::Col<double> directAccessResult1(n);
   arma::Col<double> directAccessResult2(n);
   arma::Col<double> armaAccess1(n);
   arma::Col<double> armaAccess2(n);
   arma::Col<double> armaAccessResult1(n);
   arma::Col<double> armaAccessResult2(n);
   std::valarray<double> valArrayAccess1(n);
   std::valarray<double> valArrayAccess2(n);
   std::valarray<double> valArrayAccessResult1(n);
   std::valarray<double> valArrayAccessResult2(n);
   // Prefil
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      directAccess1[i] = i;
      directAccess2[i] = n - i;
      armaAccess1[i] = i;
      armaAccess2[i] = n - i;
      valArrayAccess1[i] = i;
      valArrayAccess2[i] = n - i;
   }
   timer.Start();
   for (int j = 0; j < numberOfLoops; j++) {
      for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
         directAccessResult1[i] = -directAccess1[i] / (directAccess1[i] + directAccess1[i - 1]) *  directAccess2[i - 1];
         directAccessResult2[i] = -directAccess1[i] / (directAccess1[i] + directAccess1[i]) *  directAccess2[i];
      }
   }
   timer.StopAndPrint("Direct Array Indexing Took");
   std::cout << std::endl;

   timer.Start();
   for (int j = 0; j < numberOfLoops; j++) {
      armaAccessResult1.rows(1, n - 1) = -armaAccess1.rows(1, n - 1) / (armaAccess1.rows(1, n - 1) + armaAccess1.rows(0, n - 2)) % armaAccess2.rows(0, n - 2);
      armaAccessResult2.rows(1, n - 1) = -armaAccess1.rows(1, n - 1) / (armaAccess1.rows(1, n - 1) + armaAccess1.rows(1, n - 1)) % armaAccess2.rows(1, n - 1);
   }
   timer.StopAndPrint("Arma Array Indexing Took");
   std::cout << std::endl;

   timer.Start();
   for (int j = 0; j < numberOfLoops; j++) {
      for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
         valArrayAccessResult1[i] = -valArrayAccess1[i] / (valArrayAccess1[i] + valArrayAccess1[i - 1]) *  valArrayAccess2[i - 1];
         valArrayAccessResult2[i] = -valArrayAccess1[i] / (valArrayAccess1[i] + valArrayAccess1[i]) *  valArrayAccess2[i];
      }
   }
   timer.StopAndPrint("Valarray Array Indexing Took:");
   std::cout << std::endl;
```

In vs release mode (/02 - to avoid armadillo array indexing checks), they produce the following timings:

```
Started Performance Analysis!
Direct Array Indexing Took: 37.294 seconds elapsed
Arma Array Indexing Took: 39.4292 seconds elapsed
Valarray Array Indexing Took:: 37.2354 seconds elapsed
```

Comment: Perhaps it is better to use the aux memory constructors to take memory "slices" of these arrays and perform the calculations at entire row level?

Answer (score 0):

Your direct code is already quite optimal, so expression templates are not going to help here.

However, you may want to make sure the optimization level in your compiler actually enables auto-vectorization (-O3 in gcc). Secondly, you can get a bit of extra speed by `#define ARMA_NO_DEBUG` before including the Armadillo header. This will turn off all run-time checks (such as bound checks for [element access](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#element_access)), but this is not recommended until you have completely debugged your program.